# image in title of navigation bar in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, title

I have made an iPad application, in that I used navigation control,

now in the title bar , I want to put image on left side, so I hide title bar with label, but label is not covering entire width of title bar,

IL APP IN THE SCREEN SHOT,

here is the code snippet,

```
UILabel *titleView = (UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
    if (!titleView) {
        titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 50)];
        titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
        titleView.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];

        titleView.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // Change to desired color


        titleView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

        titleView.text = @"IL APP";
        titleView.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        //self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
        [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleView];
        [titleView release];
    }
```

[image: screen]

Comment: I don't understand what your intended result is. Could you maybe explain it a little further?

Comment: in the title bar, where i written IL APP in yellow color, i want to put image there, at left side....

Comment: you have to show label in left side of navigation bar?

Comment: i want to show image in left side and title in middle..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Gama as far as your question is concerned you are asking to put an Image but your real issue being described is that the label is not covering up the title bar. To cover that properly you can use

```
UILabel *titleView = (UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView;
if (!titleView) {
    titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 32)];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    titleView.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    titleView.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // Change to desired color
    //titleView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    titleView.text = @"IL APP";
    titleView.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleView];
    [titleView release];
}
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

For using an image you can use an image view instead of a label to be assigned as the titleView for navigationItem.

Hope it helps

Comment: dude,it works fine you rock,now i want to put image in my navigation bar, how should i do this ? what changes should i do this ..

Comment: Where exactly do you want to put the image, Create an UIImageView with desired image and assign it to the titleView like you assigned the label. In case you want to use a custom image for the left or right bar button then you can use UIBarButton's initWithImage: method

Comment: I am able to put the image but unfortunalty it is always aligned at the center whereas i want it to start from left and should run across the title bar. I have created the image of the size of title bar(in portrait view) but when the application is loaded, it leaves some space from left and  right corners. Also in landscape view the space is much wider(since image size is from portrait). I can have a workaround to load the appropriate images based on the orientation but was wondering if there is better way of doing it.

Comment: In that case the first thing that click on my mind is to hide the original navigation bar and create a custom bar (placing simple view with image and buttons) with desired image and buttons. you can also have a look at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1649012?threadID=1649012&tstart=0 and  http://samsoff.es/posts/customize-uikit-with-method-swizzling

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solved your problem but I get the same result.

But you can hide navigation bar and add the `UILabel` in to your `ViewController`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;
[self.view addSubview:titleview];

UIImageView *imageNav = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"navImage.png"]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imagenav];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:imageNav];
[imageNav release];
```

Comment: i tried this, self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE; navigation bar goes away, but there is no back button inside my new page, for going  back, i want back button inside.

Comment: add one button look like back button in titleview and put the pop method of button click event

Comment: i tried this in my new navigation inside my did load method, self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = FALSE;, i got back button, but when i click on back button, it comes to home page,but  with navigation bar

Comment: put the navigation hide code in your viewWillAppear of homeViewController

Comment: i want to put image in my navigation bar, how should i do ?

Comment: try this link http://www.developers-life.com/custom-uinavigationbar-with-image-and-back-button.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi i wanted to do the same thing and i saw your posting, i basically used some of the code you provided and modified it a little and got it to work see below:

```
//declare and initialize your imageView
UIImageView *titleImage = (UIImageView *)self.navigationItem.titleView;

titleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width/2) 
- (100/2), 0, 100, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

//setting the image for UIImageView
titleImage.image = [UIImage imageName:@"photo.jpg"];
```

//NOTE: you have to do this line at the bottom to add image to the navigation bar Try it it WORKS!

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImage;
```